# How to invalidate cookies

Tags: http, cookies, session-cookies

I logged on to a website, got an http request, then simulated it in Python, and sent the script to a friend with cookie information in it. He can now use cookie to make all kinds of requests for permissions on the site, including some dangerous operations even when I changed my password.

I think I've done something stupid. How do I invalidate this cookie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to log in to the site that the cookie is associated with and then log out again. If the backend is properly developed/implemented, then old cookies should no longer be valid.

Comment: I've tried but it didn't work. Is there some other ways to invalidate this cookie, or do I have to ask him to delete the script.

Comment: if it is an API, you usually can delete the API key online, but it all depends on the site... so, perhaps ask the site owner for assistance?